Is it possible to detect when the device is connected to Carplay?
I'm working on an app that does NOT support Carplay but I wonder if it's possible to detect if the device is connected to Carplay so I can add some logic on top of it?
Any insights or documentations are greatly appreciated.

It is possible to detect when a device is connected to Carplay using the UIScreen class in iOS. Even though your app does not support Carplay, you can still detect the presence of a Carplay screen and take action based on that information.
import UIKit

class CarPlayDetectionManager {

func startMonitoringForCarPlayConnection() {
    // Add observer for screen connection
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(screenDidConnect), name: UIScreen.didConnectNotification, object: nil)
    // Add observer for screen disconnection
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(screenDidDisconnect), name: UIScreen.didDisconnectNotification, object: nil)
    
    // Check if there are already any screens connected
    for screen in UIScreen.screens {
        if screen.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == .carPlay {
            print("CarPlay screen already connected")
            handleCarPlayConnected(screen: screen)
        }
    }
}

@objc func screenDidConnect(notification: Notification) {
    if let newScreen = notification.object as? UIScreen {
        if newScreen.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == .carPlay {
            print("CarPlay screen connected")
            handleCarPlayConnected(screen: newScreen)
        }
    }
}

@objc func screenDidDisconnect(notification: Notification) {
    if let disconnectedScreen = notification.object as? UIScreen {
        if disconnectedScreen.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == .carPlay {
            print("CarPlay screen disconnected")
            handleCarPlayDisconnected(screen: disconnectedScreen)
        }
    }
}

func handleCarPlayConnected(screen: UIScreen) {
    // Add your custom logic when CarPlay is connected
}

func handleCarPlayDisconnected(screen: UIScreen) {
    // Add your custom logic when CarPlay is disconnected
}

func stopMonitoring() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIScreen.didConnectNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIScreen.didDisconnectNotification, object: nil)
}

}

Thanks for your response. They looks promissing. Can we somehow simulate those states as I don't have a real car.

Yes, you can simulate CarPlay connections using the iOS Simulator in Xcode. Here’s how you can do it: Launch iOS Simulator in Xcode ->> Select the "I/O" menu in the simulator ->> Go to "External Displays", and from there, you can add a simulated CarPlay screen. The simulator will then behave as if it’s connected to a CarPlay-compatible system. By doing this, you can trigger the same notifications that you would receive if an actual device were connected to CarPlay. This should allow you to test the connection and disconnection logic you’ve implemented in your app.

Yes, you can detect if your phone is connected to CarPlay (without relaying on which screen is open in the application). You can use AVAudioSession to check what are the current audio inputs on the device. When you connect to CarPlay, you get a new audio input available which name is CarPlay. It works regardless the app state, whether it's in the foreground or background.
Here's the example code:
import AVFoundation

    func hasCarPlay() {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        if let inputs = audioSession.availableInputs {
            for input in inputs {
                if input.portName == "CarPlay" || input.portType == .carAudio {
                    showAlertWithMessage(title: "CarPlay Available", message: "")
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }

